# Argument Exception with Label Biding in Listbox

Tags: binding, combobox, listbox, label, argumentexception

I have the following problem. I created a Dialog where you are supposed to add entries into a `ListBox`. Each `ListBoxItem` consits of a `TextBox` for the Product Name and the Product Price (theses are properties of the Product class). Each `ListBoxItem` also has a `ComboBox` to choose a unit for the Product (e.g. kilograms, litres, or pieces).
I want the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` to be bound to the `Content` of the `Label` adjacent to the Price `TextBox` so that the `Label` reads "€/SelectedItem" (e.g "€/kg").
But when I run the following code, I get an `ArgumentException`. Hope somebody can help me.

```
<ListBox Name="lbProducts" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="tbDProductName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" />
            <TextBox Name="tbDPrice" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Name="lbDPriceSign" Content="{Binding ElementName=cbDAmount, Path=SelectedItem}"  FontSize="16" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbDAmount" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="kg" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="l"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Stk"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox Name="tbDAmount" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Amount}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You might want to re-tag to include the language/framework/platform involved - the control types are platform-agnostic, therefore it doesn't say anything about the technology used. WPF for instance may be a good start... ;)

Comment: the code that you have provided compiles and does not throw an exception. Can you provide the code which actually doesn't work?